# Java: How to write an image after my own compression

Tags: java, image

I´m working on small project in Java where I load an image (BMP format, with method ImageIO.read()), use jpeg compression algorithm and finally i want to save it (write image). Method ImageIO.write does its own compression when i want to save image. Are there any possibilities how to write compressed image with my own compression?

Note: i want to save it as jpg file

Note 2: In the same way i want to implement jpg decoder and i will need to save bmp file (I hope that it is same case as jpg saving)

Comment: Its quite difficult, however creating png is easy.

Comment: @libik - Unfortunately pngs are big.

Comment: @RudiKershaw - yes, but if you need it for something real, why you do not use library and you want to do your own compression?

Comment: If you have already done the compression you need, can you not just write it as an ordinary binary file? If not, what have you compressed and what parts need additional work

Comment: @libik - It is my school project where i have to show my knowledge in jpeg encoding/decoding and it is written in Java because i don´t like C language and don´t know C++:)

Comment: @matesx - ah, so you do have finished ImageIO.read method and you only need to write it to file?

Comment: @Woody On output of algorithm i have BufferedImage (or it maybe File), so I just edit output of algorithm to File , create FileInputStream, get binary data, create FileOutputStream and write it? What about extension, it will be file with jpg extension?

Comment: @libik I can read image as BMP file for encoding to jpg via ImageIO.read, and JPG file for decoding in the same way. So yes, i only need to write it.

Comment: Depends what you have. If you load in an image and do a jpeg compression on it, you are left with a block of data that is the image, a set of hufman tables, a set of quantisation tables and some data about the original image you have to write as well as option exif info. The whole thing is arranged in a tiff structure on disk with blocks of data, so it is much more complicated than 'just' the compression. Do you actually have to write the file to show your understanding? can you not display the tables and image data?

Comment: @Woody I had no idea that it would be so difficult to write the file. I will display resulting image data on JPanel (i´m working on it). In requirements i have to have output file in jpg format (encoding) or bmp format (decoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)'s javadoc, you'll see, that one may use an (existing) ImageWriter. With that one may set different options.

How this fits into your school project I do not know. Using an existing ImageWriter, with options might be one possibility.

Writing your ImageWriter including the compression I do not entirely consider school level or that educational.

A start might be to look at [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/imageio/compress-a-jpeg-file/).

Comment: Probably this is what i´m looking for. Thank you